# installscript msi manually altering feature to be considered installed

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript-msi

Here's our problem: we have a product that we use an Installscript MSI to install.  At one point we switched to a completely new Installscript MSI to handle versioning properly and restructure the features.  During this time, a majority of the installer remained the same, such as our database.  At more than one installation site, since the database already existed, and we didn't want the installer to drop/create the database, we decided to uncheck the database feature.

Fast forward a year, we are now doing product upgrades that modify the structure of the database.  Because we neglected to install the database feature when we ran the newer installer, these SQL scripts are not being run.  This is a major problem since we would like to continue upgrading our product in this manner.  My question is: is there a simple way of altering the installation (MSI database?) so that the database feature is considered to be installed?

Some stipulations: We are not considering the option to rerun the setup and add the feature that way.  The installer was not properly designed to handle this elegantly.

Comment: Are you using Major Upgrades? If so, what is your Migrate Feature States set to?

Comment: We use minor upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

[Major Upgrade vs. Minor Upgrade vs. Small Update](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/MajorMinorSmall.htm)

Restructuring the feature tree is not supported by Windows Installer in a minor upgrade scenario.  This requires a major upgrade.

Comment: We're far beyond this stage.  Right now I am simply trying to peek into the MSI database for the installer and set some sort of "IsInstalled" boolean to true for a specific feature without doing it the intended way because we don't want to deal with the side effects of dropping/creating the entire database.